# How to install two applications/packages simultaneously?

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management

Example:
FlightGear (2GB) is installing and I just need to install udftools quickly, and I wish not to break the giant flightgear installation for that.

Windows also supports installing two programs simultaneously, but if I try it on Linux, even on a different user and tty, it fails.

How do I install two applications simultaneously?

Comment: If you interrupt the download, it should resume where it left off when you restart the installation.

Comment: "on Linux" -- there are a lot more package managers in the Linux world than just apt. Most of them have a mutex around package-database changes, but that's not completely universal -- for a counterexample, see NixOS; for another, see Gentoo. It would be more fair to ask why you can't install more than one package at a time "on Ubuntu" or "on Debian" than "on Linux".

Comment: @Charles Duffy Well, he did add the `apt` tag, so this is really `apt` specific. The answer would be the same for Ubuntu or Debian. It really is for all Linux distros that use `apt`.

Comment: @JoL, ...yup, that's why the above is just a comment, not a proposed edit.

Comment: @JoL It's also relevant to `yum`, since it uses a similar locking mechanism.

Comment: The built-in Windows "Package Manager" doesn't actually allow installing two programs simultaneously. But custom installers often sidestep this.

Comment: @MooingDuck Exactly. If Windows installer is executed twice, you will see that 'Another installation is already in progress' dialog.

Answer (score 18):

You can’t; APT, just like most other package managers, uses a lock to ensure that a single package management operation is ever in progress at any given time. This is done to enforce consistency: it’s important to keep the state of the package database, and the state of packages, coherent, and the easiest way to do that is to guarantee that they’re never undergoing several concurrent modifications.

The locks are always in a fixed place (otherwise they wouldn’t be all that useful), so you can use them yourself to queue work up, using something like [`lockf`](https://gist.github.com/dspinellis/eb924c195206f57e896d026dbe14befa):

```
lockf /var/lib/dpkg/lock apt-get update
```

will wait for the lock to be freed (if necessary) before running `apt-get update`.

Comment: Is there anything like a queue?

Comment: @TechLord Yes. Your shell. If you ran the install for the large application from a terminal, then you can enter the next installation command on the same terminal (perhaps preparing it elsewhere and pasting it rather than typing blind). Otherwise, you might want to use the `at` command to install the other package later.

Comment: `apt` also accepts multiple package names from the CLI, or you could mark multiple packages for install in a GUI package manager, such as Synaptic. The CLI statement also holds true for `yum` based systems: you can specify multiple packages to install and it will resolve dependencies and queue them up for installation.

Answer (score 3):

Like Stephen Kitt said, you can't ask a package manager to install a package while it's already busy installing other packages because that raises concerns of consistency in the system. However, like psusi said in a comment, if your package manager is still in the step of downloading the package, that's perfectly interruptible. You can Ctrl+C, install udftools, and then reinvoke apt to continue installing your big package. It should have kept the partially downloaded package and continue the download from where it left off.

The reason why you can't invoke your package manager to install or remove things while it's already modifying the system in another process is because that would add too much complexity for little gain to have the processes communicate with each other and coordinate their actions to ensure system consistency. For example, what if you ask it to install a package that conflicts with a package that another process is somewhere in the process of installing? What if you ask it to remove a package that another process had already checked was installed because the packages it's going to install depend on it? What if you ask it to install a package that depends on a package another process in installing right now, but the dependent package ends up being installed first because it won the race condition and runs an installation script that depends on the package that hasn't finished installing?

It's just simpler and safer to use a lock to restrict one process at a time.

Comment: Sad, but fine. How can I make an automatic installation queue?

Comment: You can try to make something like that, but for your case, isn't it simpler to just interrupt the download, install the other package, and reinvoke the installation of the big package, like I and psusi said?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running for installation queue

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, it's reasonable to assume some common-or-garden flight simulator, even an enormous one, will not be making changes to the same parts of the filesystem that `udftools` does.

I know that if `yum` is preoccupied by some larger transaction, then *`rpm` can still be used to install, upgrade, or erase packages*, because `yum` creates a lock that other `yum` processes must respect, but `rpm` does not need to.

Similarly, `dpkg` can be used to install `.deb` packages without having to negotiate with `apt`, although they might be more closely integrated, in which case if you're prepared to eat the risk, go ahead and delete `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`. I mean, what the heck? it's only *the integrity of your entire OS package database!*

Comment: "it's reasonable to assume a flight simulator will not be making changes to the same parts of the filesystem that udftools does"... except in the package database.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm constantly reading that `apt` is soooo much better than `yum` and since (as I explain) `yum` can handle `rpm` making changes to the rpmdb, I expect `apt` will be able to handle its buddy `dpkg` doing a similar extremely dangerous thing. And it'll do it _that much better_ than `yum`, too!

Comment: @Rich To be fair, you don't really explain that `yum` can handle `rpm` making changes to the rpmdb, you merely state that `rpm` doesn't respect `yum`'s locks. It doesn't automatically follow that `yum` won't crash and burn spectacularly when it finds the rpmdb has been modified regardless of its lock. `yum` may be fine, I don't know, but your answer does not imply that it will be – only that you can play with fire if you want to.

Comment: @justinpawela That's kinda the implication I wanted to set out. It's a risk. I figure a gaming computer is a place where this kind of risk might be acceptable. (But since you point out I need to clarify: yes, `yum` allows it, and next run it whines about `rpmdb altered outside of yum`. It's not as though _something other than_ an `rpm`-related command altered the rpmdb.)